# Rename [linuxmint] to [linux-mint]; make [mint] a synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[linuxmint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linuxmint) (587 questions) and [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) (369 questions) are both about [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint). Using "linux-mint" instead of those two would better follow the naming conventions.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to check that none of the [tag:mint] questions are about [the analytics software](http://www.haveamint.com/).

Comment: I just scanned the 195 questions; they all appear related to Linux Mint.

Answer (score 3):

For the rename, yes and done. We usually use the hyphen to separate two words (see related meta: [Should tags take the form foobar or foo-bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-tags-take-the-form-foobar-or-foo-bar)). I renamed the tag as [linux-mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint).

For the synonym, I checked the 433 questions with the tag [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint). Most of them were related to Linux Mint. I went through all the [questions that weren't tagged with linux, or had the linux word in their body](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmint%5D+-%22linux%22+-%5Blinux%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0), there were 52 of them. All of them were related to Linux Mint itself. Therefore, I added [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) as synonym for [linux-mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint). That is [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) (x 433) → [linux-mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) (x 750). I will wait for a couple of days and then merge, just in case, there are any concerns about the synonym.

So yep, this is completed, and within 5 years.