# Can we reuse tag [mint] that is now being redirected to [linux-mint]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I recently read the article *[Mint: A new language designed for building single page applications](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/29/mint-a-new-language-designed-for-building-single-page-applications/)* and decided to try it.

Today I tried to search for questions about this Mint programming language on Stack Overflow using tag [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint). However, the result is that I got redirected to tag [linux-mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) and that is not what I wanted to see for the tag [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint), which I think should be referred to the Mint programming language instead because now that [linux-mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) already has its own tag.

I later found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274335/rename-linuxmint-to-linux-mint-make-mint-a-synonym) related topic that might be a good reference that the work on separating both tags are done. Therefore, I think [mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) can/should be used for the Mint programming language now.

For what it's worth, I neither have seen any questions nor I myself have any questions about it. I just think that it should have its own tag for a tag name that is not being used. The language was even just featured on the website.

Comment: I think you'll get a lot of linux-mint questions in that tag.

Comment: Perhaps [tag:mint-language] would be better

Comment: Ugh, Mint is another one of those names that are *terrible* for a programming thing. Tried to search for "mint loop array" (generic programming thing to do in the language) and the results I get are Bash scripting (because Linux Mint), also Bash scripting (from the Tec**Mint** website), the wikipedia article on foreach loops (the language *is* mentioned there), loops in PHP (Linux Mint is mentioned on the page. Dunno why), article on installing Linux Mint (because it mentions /dev/loop0), article on loops and arrays in Java (because it mentions mint candies).

Comment: With "mint loop array" I would have expected something like https://www.twenty20.com/photos/58092791 - just with mint flavour.

Comment: Dear language/framework/library developers; please stop using common words as names for things. It messes up our tagging system. kthxbye

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's a common word, indeed: https://library.e.abb.com/public/9ec9c59478364ccfbef5fb85a4423c82/LT0255A03.pdf

Comment: Unless it's a really cryptic name, I prefer "<name>-language" as tag to make sure it won't become an ambiguous thing in the future. Fun fact, MINT (Mathe, Information, Naturwissenschaften und Technik) is also the German counterpart of STEM (Science, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics).

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, the same with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) (excellent product, though. Or rather the least worst).

Comment: @Paulie_D Agreed, but I would recommend [mint-lang]] as the usual nomenclature vs [mint-language]

Answer (score 11):

Let's not.

Common and/or short words as tags nearly [always backfire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412181/6296561) and just create work that we don't really want more of. A number of conflicts with [mint] have already been outlined in the comments, and those are just the tip of the iceberg.

Use [mint-language], [mint-lang] (with or without the dash), or something else instead, as long as it's explicit about which mint the tag is for. The tag has to be created first, however; I'm not seeing an existing tag at the time of writing.

Comment: `[mint-lang]` looks like a *logical* Choice to me..., this is also how the [Web-Site](https://mint-lang.com/) is called, and also the Name of the [Repository](https://github.com/mint-lang/mint) on 'GitHub'... + also the 'Twitter' [Account](https://twitter.com/mint_lang?lang=en) (both with Dash or Underscore) and already the best Keyword to use also in '[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mint-lang)'...