# Tags: "cue" or "cuelang"?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

CUE is "an open source language, with a rich set of APIs and tooling, for defining, generating, and validating all kinds of data" (to quote https://cuelang.org/). I asked a question about CUE a few weeks ago; yesterday I noticed that the tag [cue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cue) that I had originally used has been replaced with [cuelang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuelang). There are currently 4 questions with this tag. But since the name of the programming language is CUE, I think the tag should be [cue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cue) as well? After all, we don't have [golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang), [rustlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rustlang), [phplang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phplang) etc. etc., so why [cuelang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuelang)?

Comment: We generally add a disambiguating identifier for certain words; this is one of them. `cue` immediately sounds like a tag that's gonna be misused for anything involving the physical cue object, the abstract concept of a cue, as well as cue cards, etc. to avoid that, it's better if the cue language tag is called cuelang. There's also a couple examples of this in practice as well, including [tag:nim-lang], [tag:crystal-lang], and [tag:logo-lang]

Comment: @Zoe [tag:crystal-lang]? Geez, we might as well retag [tag:python] to python-lang to make sure people don't ask questions about snakes

Comment: @Nick You'd think that, but there's another programming-related tool called [crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crystal-reports/info) (possibly just crystal as well, there's something called crystal-space-3d which seems to be related, but I'm not an SME and I have no clue). So there's a conflict with something actually used in programming, justifying a disambiguation. In the case of cue, cue cards, concepts, and the object are all things that show up in apps (flash card apps, anyone?) and games (there's _lots_ of implementations of 8 ball pool).

Comment: [tag:golang] exists, as a synonym for [tag:go].

Comment: Am I supposed to say [cue] or [cuelang]? Can someone provide me with a cue?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: yeah, because "golang" is more search-engine friendly than "Go" (ironic if you think that it was invented at Google). Also "golang.org" was the original website - but "Go" is still the official name, and actually the Go team seems to dislike "golang" so much that they changed the website to "go.dev" recently (of course that probably wasn't the main reason for the change, but I think it contributed to the decision).

Comment: There's even an [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang) about it.

Comment: @rob74: They also stepped on [a chess-like game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) with a history of many thousands of years.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did it in an attempt to disambiguate the *cue* tag before it's too late.

There were 39 questions with the tag,

- 4 of them were about [cuelang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuelang),
- 7 of them were about [cue-sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cue-sheet)s,
- and 12 of them were about [cue-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cue-points).

I retagged those. The rest were about stuff that don't warrant new tags, so I removed the tag from them.

In short, it's *cuelang* because *cue* is ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! Makes sense, "Cue" is more ambiguous (not to mention less well-known) than "Go", "Rust", "PHP" etc.. Maybe they should have taken an example from the band R.E.M. and called it C.U.E. - after all the name stands for "Configure Unify Execute"...

Comment: Shouldn't it be called `cue-lang` instead of [tag:cuelang]? To be coherent with the existing [tag:nim-lang], [tag:crystal-lang] or [tag:logo-lang] (c.f. Zoe comment on the question).

Comment: I also agree with changing it to `cue-lang`, since it's a language, and the name of the language itself isn't "Cuelang". I did a quick peek at [`*lang` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*lang), and it looks like the tags which don't have a hyphen generally are actually named *x*lang, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @rob74, the vast majority of acronyms don't have period separators. Laser, LED, modem, TWAIN, PHP, and probably millions more. So why would the makers of Cue even think about putting in periods? Just to disambiguate on SE? Not to mention that most people don't put the periods in REM when referencing the band, rather than the medical term with the same meaning.

Comment: @computercarguy: But then there is [D.A.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.A.D._(band)) - [sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPH0uqKoDFY&t=1h5m20s) (not to be taken too seriously).